# Apple Mail 8: How to display mails in plain text?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

Is there an option in Apple Mail 8 to have mails displayed in plain text format? I cannot find a setting for it and [the classic way to disable it does not seem to work anymore](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/Make_Mac_OS_X_Mail_Prefer_Plain_Text_for_Displaying_Mail.htm).

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: No, sorry. I use Gnome Evolution now